# Your Oscilloscope has ExPloDEd ! Make a sine wave

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art

**[ CODE GOLF]**

---

## BAM! - Fire and Smoke

**Your Oscilloscope has exploded from one too many waves.**

---

Re-create these waves assuming the following:

- All waves are **Sine Waves**
- An amplitude of **`1`** spans **`3 lines`** (*Therefore and amplitude of `2` would span `5 lines`*) *[Vertically]*
- We want to see **`100`** characters worth of sine (*Can be any char*) *[Horizontally]*
- **`12`** characters per Period is a frequency of **`1Hz`**

```
[Amplitude of 1 and Frequency of 1Hz with a Span of 45 Characters]
>SinASCII('a1','f1')

   ...         ...         ...             >            
...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    >[cont. for 100 char] 
         ...         ...         ...       >
```

---

## Inputs

Inputs can be in any format but must be explicitly stated if different from standard (*below*) and must contain:

- Amplitude
- Frequency

**Test inputs:**  `[('a2', 'f0.5'), ('a4', 'f1'), ('a6', 'f2'), ('a1','f0.25')]`

---

### This is a CODE GOLF Challenge

**Some Clarification**

Because sine is a continuous function, the values must be discretized:
For the case of `amplitude of 1` and `frequency of 1Hz` the "Crest" of the sine wave must be on `line 1` and the "Trough" of the sine wave must be on `line 3`.

To achieve the intermediate points, the wave points are set corresponding to ranges associated to the sections of the wave and these ranges will be relative to the amplitude.

[Wikipedia - Crest and Trough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_and_trough)

Comment: Please define how exactly the position of the dots needs to be determined - the sine wave is a continuous function and there is no cannonical was of translating it to a discrete grid like in your case.

Comment: I would think that an amplitude of 2 would span 5 lines vertically, rather than 6. The y values would be: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MitchellSpector - You are correct - I'll  fix it

Comment: Also, the 1 Hz output example you gave appears to have a period of 12, not 15. Which one would you like people to use?

Comment: @MitchellSpector Yes, I was 'umming' and 'ahhing' on the overlapping points - You are correct and it will be updated.

Comment: The specs are still not sufficient to define a "nice" sine wave. Please make it unambiguous, or if you want to leave certain choices to the reader please exactly specify them.

Comment: @flawr "Cannonical" I see what you did there

Comment: Presumably each point on the graph should be the desired point on the sine curve (with the right period and amplitude), rounded and/or truncated to an integer.

Comment: "Can be any char" does that mean that the background and foreground may be any characters, or must the background be made from spaces?

Comment: Are we free to display any phase we wish?

Comment: @Noodle9 Functions are allowed unless explicitly disallowed (even saying "write a program which..." does not disallow them here).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21? 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

[21 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//w5fisa7ItzLDlzMwwrDDhlPDlysxLuG4nivEllXFkuG5rFn///8wLjQy/zQ) if we may use a non-space character for the background.

```
×Ɱȷ2×30°ÆS×+1.Ḟ+Ṭ€o⁶z⁶Y
```

A full program accepting frequency (a float) and amplitude (an integer) which prints the result using `1` as the wave and  as the background.
Note: Since there is no mention of phase I have assumed we may pick any (I also asked for clarification).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//w5fisa7ItzLDlzMwwrDDhlPDlysxLuG4nivhuazigqxv4oG2euKBtln///8uNDL/NA)**

Comment: Snap (well almost), though I’ve made fewer assumptions than you about phase. I also missed that `×30°` was equivalent to `÷6×OP`, and the allowance for any character. I think I’ll delete mine since it’s too close to yours to make it worthwhile keeping both.

Comment: No need to delete similar answers (or even identical ones), golfers do tend to converge on the same methods!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>128</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>107</s></sup> 103 bytes

Added a byte to fix and error kindly pointed out by [blueteeth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34766/blueteeth).
Saved <s>23</s> 27 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!!!
Added a byte to fix a fudge kindly pointed out by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

```python
lambda a,f:[[' .'[~j<=a*sin(f*i*pi/6)+.5<-j]for i in range(100)]for j in range(~a,a)]
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY27DoIwGEZ3nqJbL5YKGggh8CTI8BsttKGX1C4uvHoVY6KjrifnfJ@/x9nZY5r6U1rAnC@AgMt2GDASeFh11wO7KUskU8yrfU13oupyPUoXkELKogB2upKyKOiL6Q9bgQMdMxmcQQbijJTxLkSWNm/ZvIk0vBCHirY@KBsJxkK759lCafYmOWbbdvbV1Lz8Lyh/CVJKDw)

Inputs an integral amplitude and a float for frequency.
Uses a period of 12 characters for 1Hz.
Returns a list of lists of characters.

Comment: For `g(1, 1)` this has 3 lines, but the first is empty. So it doesn't match the example.

Comment: @blueteeth Ok, now it's on three line - thanks! :-)

Comment: Save 23 by constructing as you go, inlining everything into list comprehensions and thus a lambda (with a little `~` magic sprinkled in) - [TIO](https://tio.run/##jY07DsIwEAX7nGI7e60QYpAoIuUkIcUicLJR/JFxQ5OrG4yQoKQdzXsTHmn27pin/pxXspcrAdWmGwYBjRjYJambgyJ1ZyeNYhV4f0Ls@20ZjY/AwA4iuekmddvimy1ftlFNOFYmeguW0gxsg49J5eKtxZvkqdbYhVhSQjSLf4VWxOpDdkKV4@pnoP8Z5Jyf)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Wow! Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: With different rounding [we can save 4](https://tio.run/##lY27DoIwGEZ3nqJbL5YKGggh8CTI8BsttKGX1C4uvHoVY6KjrifnfJ@/x9nZY5r6U1rAnC@AgMt2GDASeFh11wO7KUskU8yrfU13oupyPUoXkELKogB2upKyKOiL6Q9bgQMdMxmcQQbijJTxLkSWNm/ZvIk0vBCHirY@KBsJxkK759lCafYmOWbbdvbV1Lz8Lyh/CVJKDw)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Absolutely brilliant - thanks! :-)